# View's handler not being cleared when view is destroyed

Tags: android, view, nullpointerexception, handler

I noticed that view's handler is not being cleared when view is destroyed.
Looking at this sample code:

```
Handler viewHandler = view.getHandler();
if (viewHandler != null) {
    viewHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.doSmth();
        }
    });
}
```

On rare occassion it might throw `NullPointerException` inside `run()` method.

Do you guys have any solution to this problem, which **is not** creating a separate handler in every class (and managing it manually) whenever I want to perform some action on UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Handler viewHandler = view.getHandler();
    if (viewHandler != null) {
        Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.doSmth();
            }
        };
        viewHandler.post(runnable);
    }
```

And in onStop()

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    viewHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
  }
```

Comment: The point is I want it to be independent from `Activity` lifecycle.

Comment: writing handlers without reference will cause memory leak in the app.